# Why does this JSP-like ASPX markup work?

Tags: html, asp.net, jsp

I am stumped by something that works and produces correct `HTML` output but shouldn't, according to my understanding of `ASPX`. I need someone to help me figure out the magic. It is hard to search for this specific phenomenon and I tried, but to no avail, so here goes:

My colleague is currently working on migrating an `JSP` project to `ASPX`. In `JSP` it is allowed to use server side controls inside of attribute values, like this:

```
<a href="<myServerSideJSPControl mode="test" />" />
```

Note the double quotes used to delimit both the `href` attribute of the `HTML` anchor tag and the inner control's attribute value. This works for `JSP`, which is strange as it is but I can accept that since I am not a `JSP` developer and thus simply assume the `JSP` compiler pulls off some fancy, smart tricks.

Now my colleague asked me how to translate this to `ASPX` and if he could use this pattern in spite of any `Visual Studio Intellisense` warnings - and I said no. I was 100% sure this would never ever compile.

Then, just for demonstration purposes, I created a new `Visual Studio ASPX` project and entered the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <img src="<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></asp:Literal> " />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And believe it or not: it works! Hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> opens the browser and displays a `lorempixel` image. And the `HTML` source looks perfectly fine like this (hidden `ASPX` stuff like `ViewState` omitted for brevity):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="./WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">
            <div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100 ">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please explain to me how the `ASPX` parser manages to perform this miracle? Why do the double quotes not break the document structure and how is the inner `ASPX` control correctly distinguished from the rest of the markup? Please set my world view straight! ;)

Comment: Maybe you'd better migrate to Razor instead?

Comment: We're not trying to find the best target framework for migration. Razor can handle similar stuff, I know that. But I want to understand how the ASPX parser works in situations like these.

Comment: O, that's simple. Imagine that you're looking at crowd (or queue) and trying to find only people with green hats. Green hats and nothing else.
Someone with hat too? Is it green? Nope? Good bye, only green hats allowed.

Comment: That assumes that you only get a set of hats (or tokens). But the parser gets a set of threads (characters) that make up individual hats (tokenizing). And both sets (the green hats and the hats with other colors) are delimited by threads of the same color (the double quote characters)... How does the parser distinguish between the double quotes that belong to an HTML attribute and ones that belong to the ASP.NET control's attribute?

Comment: One option could be that the parser is in html mode until it reaches `<asp:` and switches to ASP.NET mode. Before reaching that mode it doesn't care about any quotes.